# Removing small gaps between lines in LaTeX lstlisting output

Tags: spacing, listings

Whenever I set a somewhat dark background color in a code listing it becomes obvious that there are small line separations, these of course stay white making the overall appearance not desirable. My working example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mc-background}{rgb}{0.569,0.612,0.525}
\definecolor{mc-comment}{rgb}{0.620,0.216,0.243}
\definecolor{mc-keyword}{rgb}{0.820,0.725,0.576}
\definecolor{mc-string}{rgb}{0.769,0.353,0.231}
\definecolor{mc-basic}{rgb}{0.169,0.180,0.212}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\lstset{
  language=bash,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mc-background},
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{mc-basic},
  keywordstyle=\color{mc-keyword},
  commentstyle=\color{mc-comment},
  stringstyle=\color{mc-string},
  tabsize=4,
  aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
  columns=fixed,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  frame=single,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  title=\lstname
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/bash
:(){ :|:& };:
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to remove the gap that this produces?

Comment: Added content here and found out comment can't include code, moved to original post as edit.

Comment: After compiling your code I can't see any white line. Can you point more specifically to the problem? (I added a screenshot to your post)

Comment: It is a artifact of the PDF viewer. If you view in Acrobat it appears ok until you zoom in and then at certain zoom levels it shows up. But zooming in even further, the lines are not visible.

Comment: Yeah, the same thing with sumatra pdf. If you zoom in far enough, the lines disappear, but you have to zoom in quite far. Have you tried printing the document to see if the white lines appear than?

Comment: in okular I can't see the lines at any zooming percentage

Comment: Those (spurrious?) lines also show up in Preview (Mac OS 10.8.3).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I probably should have tried it on a different viewer than evince. As suggested by the comments that is definitely the issue. Thanks.