# lstlisting - bold numbers, remove gaps between lines

Tags: color, listings, line-numbering, lstdefinestyle

I am trying to make a coloured source code box with `lstlisting`. Nearly everything works fine except two things:

1. I gave up after 2 hours of searching the web on how to make the little numbers in front of the lines bold. I tried `\large` and `\huge` with no luck (like you can see in the image below). Then I tried with `\textbf{}`, but i did not find out what to put inside the brackets. Is there a way to make the numbers bold?
2. After exporting to PDF I noticed that there are some strange white lines between the code lines (see image below). Where do they come from? Could they be removed?

[image: example of gaps between the lines]

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%
% ----- basic setup -----
%

\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

%
% ----- definitions -----
%

\lstdefinestyle{bashcode}{
    language=bash,
    backgroundcolor=\color{darkgray},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{white},
    frame=tb,
    framerule=0pt,
    framesep=10pt,
    framexleftmargin=20pt,
    framexrightmargin=10pt,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\color{cyan}
}

\lstdefinestyle{bashcode2}{
    language=bash,
    backgroundcolor=\color{darkgray},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{white},
    frame=tb,
    framerule=0pt,
    framesep=10pt,
    framexleftmargin=20pt,
    framexrightmargin=10pt,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\large\color{cyan}
}

\lstdefinestyle{bashcode3}{
    language=bash,
    backgroundcolor=\color{darkgray},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{white},
    frame=tb,
    framerule=0pt,
    framesep=10pt,
    framexleftmargin=20pt,
    framexrightmargin=10pt,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\huge\color{cyan}
}

%
% ===== begin of document =====
%

\begin{document}

\lstset{style=bashcode}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={installing git}\label{src:install_git}]
sudo apt-get install git
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{style=bashcode2}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={installing git}\label{src:install_git2}]
sudo apt-get install git
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{style=bashcode3}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={installing git}\label{src:install_git3}]
sudo apt-get install git
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second question is a viewer issue, see [Removing small gaps between lines in LaTeX lstlisting output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104138/3323).

Comment: what about `numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\bfseries`?

Comment: Thanks to jpayansomet, `\bfseries` seems to work as expected!

Comment: Regarding the background color: you could use tcolorbox and its listings library.

Comment: Any news here? Have you solved you issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments